# Splitting dataset into train, test and validation sets to maintain proportions

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, computer-vision, training-data

I am working with the [iWildCam dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/iwildcam-2020-fgvc7), and I am trying to split my dataset so that it maintains the proportions of animals in the train, test and validation sets, while at the same time, ensuring that images from the same sequence do not occur in the training and test sets.

To provide some more context, each image belongs to a sequence. This dataset is a collection of images from camera traps and so sometimes images belong to the same sequence. So I have to make sure that if an image from a sequence is used to train my model, then it shouldn't be present in the test set. To add some additional complexity to this problem, each image is assigned a category (basically what kind of animal is in the image).

So in addition to making sure that images from the same sequence do not occur in testing and training sets, I also need to try to make sure that the proportions of categories in the training, test and validations is the same (I would appreciate any thoughts on whether this is even necessary).

I am not entirely sure how to approach this. I have tried using [GroupKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold.html) from sklearn and I have managed to get folds with the following distribution of the image categories.

[Bar graph showing the distribution of categories in the folds generated by GroupKFold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gtY9.png)

Any suggestions for how I can go about achieving this will be very helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: you mean - https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did look into that but in my post I also talked about each image belonging sequences. I want to make sure that if image x and y appear in the same sequence of images, then x shouldn't appear in the training and y shouldn't appear in the testing. Because sequences of images are "similar" images and if the model sees an image x in training and if it sees image y in testing, it would have already seen a very similar image during training (i.e. image x). Which is why I was using GroupKFold in the first place.